# Eigenvalues for a sparse matrix

Tags: julia, linear-algebra

I have a large sparse matrix, A: 44668×44668 SparseMatrixCSC{Any, Int64} with 32219901 stored entries

I just want eigenvalues of it, ideally all of them, but also setting on a few of the most positive and most negative, in order to get a sense of definiteness.

I have tried the following and they aren't working:

```
julia> using Arpack
julia> eigs(A)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching zero(::Type{Any})
```

```
julia> KrylovKit.eigsolve(A)
ERROR: ArgumentError: Sampler for this object is not defined
```

I have failed to convert this to a dense matrix, which suggests something wrong with my matrix

```
julia> a = Matrix(A)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching zero(::Type{Any})
```

Comment: Yep, your matrix isn't in good health. Can you show us how it is initialized?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you can try converting the entries in your sparse matrix to a numeric type.

```
using LinearAlgebra, SparseArrays

# Convert matrix entries to Float64
A_float = sparse(Matrix(A), Float64)

# Calculate eigenvalues using Arpack
eigenvalues = eigen(A_float).values
```

By converting the entries to a numeric type, you should be able to calculate the eigenvalues of your sparse matrix.

Comment: I get the same error: ERROR: MethodError: no method matching zero(::Type{Any})

Comment: why do you have a `Matrix{Any}` in the first place? That's your problem